Сделать фоновое приложение для выполнение функций с текстом
К примеру, сделать простое приложение, для фоновой обработки текста, которое бы при запуске висело в фоновом режиме или трее.
Пример, запускаем приложение, потом выделяем любой текст или копируем его в буфер + нажимаем какие-то горячии клавиши, после чего текст обрабатывается так как нам нужно и возвращает это в буфер ?
Может можно как-то сделать это проще ?
К примеру, убрать с текста все точки и запятые и вернуть его обратно в буфер, на выходе мы вставляем чистый текст.
Это как пример, легче не придумал.

раз, два. Главный вопрос, вам винформы, wpf или что-то другое интересно?
